# How to get ionic radii for coordination number 12?

Tags: crystal-structure, ionic-compounds, atomic-radius, crystallography, ceramics

I am studying $\ce{ABX3}$ perovskites, and I would like to calculate Goldschmidt tolerance factors for them. The $\ce{A}$ sites in these materials have a coordination number $12$.

The Shannon's paper (R. D. Shannon, Revised effective ionic radii and systematic studies of interatomic distances in halides and chalcogenides. *Acta. Cryst. A* 32, 751 (**1976**)) provides values for ionic radii for the coordination number $12$ only for a few elements, but doesn't do it for most other elements.

Are there any sources, where I can get ionic radii for $\text{C.N.} = 12$ for all elements?

Comment: Goldschmit has been shown to be a [poor model to use with perovskites](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00150193.2016.1215750).

Comment: How many ionic compounds give coordination number 12?  Close-packed structures forcing like charges together don't work well for ionic compounds.  Our experimental database might be a bit limited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commonly used method of obtaining ionic radii for higher coordination numbers (C.N.) is to extrapolate values from the Shannon's scale [[1](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0567739476001551)] using the relationship between ionic radius and coordination number proposed by Zachariasen [[2](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-5088(78)90010-3)]:

> ... the bond lengths $D(N_1)$ and $D(N_2)$ for cation coordination numbers $N_1$ and $N_2$ were related as follows
>
> $$D(N_2)=D(N_1)(N_2A_1/N_1A_2)^{1/n} \tag{1}$$
>
> where $n + 1$ is the exponent in the Born repulsion term of the lattice energy and $A_1/A_2$ is the ratio of the Madelung constants. The quantity $A_1/A_2$ was taken to be $0.972$ for $N_2/N_1 = 12/9 = 8/6 = 4/3$ and $0.927$ for $N_2/N_1 = 12/8 = 9/6 = 6/4 = 3/2$.

Jia [[3](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4596(91)90388-X)] used Zachariasen's formula and published effective ionic radii for all lanthanides with C.N. $6$ to $12$.

Using the same approach, selected ionic radii for the 12-coordinated $\ce{A}$-sites in oxo-perovskites $\ce{ABO3}$ [[4](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jallcom.2003.10.017)] as well as halide perovskites $\ce{ABX3}$ [[5](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108768108032734)] have been determined.

#### References

1. Shannon, R. D. Revised Effective Ionic Radii and Systematic Studies of Interatomic Distances in Halides and Chalcogenides. *Acta Cryst. A* **1976**, 32 (5), 751–767. https://doi.org/10.1107/S0567739476001551.
2. Zachariasen, W. H. Bond Lengths in Oxygen and Halogen Compounds of d and f Elements. *Journal of the Less Common Metals* **1978**, 62, 1–7. https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-5088(78)90010-3.
3. Jia, Y. Q. Crystal Radii and Effective Ionic Radii of the Rare Earth Ions. *Journal of Solid State Chemistry* **1991**, 95 (1), 184–187. https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4596(91)90388-X.
4. Li, C.; Soh, K. C. K.; Wu, P. Formability of $\ce{ABO3}$ Perovskites. *Journal of Alloys and Compounds* **2004**, 372 (1), 40–48. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jallcom.2003.10.017.
5. Li, C.; Lu, X.; Ding, W.; Feng, L.; Gao, Y.; Guo, Z. Formability of $\ce{ABX3}$ ($\ce{X = F, Cl, Br, I}$) Halide Perovskites. *Acta Cryst. B* **2008**, 64 (6), 702–707. https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108768108032734.