# Why does the beryllium 2+ ion have a larger radius than a helium atom?

Tags: atomic-radius

$\ce{Be^2+}$ has an ionic radius of $\pu{45 pm}$, while $\ce{He}$ has a radius of only $\pu{31 pm}$. If they are isoelectronic (they both have two elections in the $\mathrm{1p}$ orbital), and $\ce{Be}$ has more protons to attract them, why doesn't $\ce{Be^2+}$ have a smaller radius?

Comment: He has VDW radisum of 140 pm, what particular radius of He are your referring to? There is more than one.

Comment: It's probably down to different definitions and/or measuring techniques.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are mixing apples and oranges.
Or, to be more precise, an ionic radius for $\ce{Be^2+}$ with coordination number (C.N.) 6 and van der Waals radius of $\ce{He}$.
To make it clear I compiled data for van der Waals and covalent radii [1, p. 9-58] as well as ionic radii [1, p. 12-13]:

$$
\begin{array}{lccccc}
\hline
\text{Element} & R_\mathrm{vdW}/\pu{Å} & R_\mathrm{cov}/\pu{Å} & \text{Ion} & \text{C.N.} & R_\mathrm{i}/\pu{Å} \\
\hline
\ce{Be} & 1.52 & 0.99 & \ce{Be^2+} & 4 & 0.27 \\
  &  &  &  & 6 & 0.45 \\
\ce{He} & 1.40 & 0.37 &  &  & \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Apparently, there is no experimental ionic radii for helium to compare with as helium, well, represents one of the most non-reactive elements.
Also, all radii set are determined using various methods and cannot be directly compared.
From the foreword [1. p. 9-58]:

> There are many scales of van der Waals radii, but they are not fully consistent with one another. The van der Waals radii determined by Bondi [...] from x-ray diffraction data, crystal densities, gas kinetic collision cross sections, critical densities, and liquid-
>   state properties are the most widely used values. [...]
>
> The covalent radii tabulated here are recommendations for single covalent bonds, 
>   and they are based on a comprehensive evaluation of experimental data [...].

Ionic radii are estimated first and foremost from the *experimental* crystal structure data, averaged and supplemented by empirical and theoretical calculations (extrapolations, e.g. using [Zachariasen method](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/103136/how-to-get-ionic-radii-for-coordination-number-12)).

#### References

1. Haynes, W. M.; Lide, D. R.; Bruno, T. J. CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics: A Ready-Reference Book of Chemical and Physical Data.; **2017**; Vol. 97. ISBN 978-1-4987-5429-3.

Comment: This is a bit over my head right now, but if I am understanding your basic point correctly, the variation is due to different types of radii and some measurement inconsistencies?

Comment: @TrumpetDude Yep, this is pretty much it.

Comment: Different types, yes. It is much like comparing the height of one man with the height of _house of_ another man, and concluding that the latter is higher. Sure, both parameters are called the same ("height"), but there is a catch.